# Ive accidentally clicked restore current snapshot, can I cancel this?

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, backup, restore, snapshot

I have accidentally clicked 'restore current snapshot' 'ok' instead of closing my last ubuntu session. I closed it immediateley without letting it load and have not opened the VM again but can see its waiting to load its saved state on next load. Is there any way to get around this and not load the saved snapshot, I don't want to lose my work.

Irony is I was just thinking 'I need to update that snapshot.'

im running Xubuntu on an oracle VM virtual box manager